# Adding a timer between animations in Java

Tags: java, animation, netbeans, timer

Hi guys so I got this issue of adding a timer between the animations, the issue with my code is that the last animation must wait a sufficient time, in order to let the previous animations to end, the code is

```
if (array1[0]>array1[1])
    {
    AnimationClass a = new AnimationClass();
    a.jButtonYUp(110, 30, 100,1, jButton6);
    a.jButtonXLeft(250, 50, 100, 1, jButton6);
    a.jButtonXRight(50, 250, 100, 1, jButton5);

  // I need the timer here about 2 seconds

    a.jButtonYDown(30, 110, 100, 1, jButton2);

    }
```

So I would greatly appreciate if somebody could direct me to the question if its already there or answer this for me

BTW that AnimationClass is a library developed by a you-tuber and I am currently following his tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (array1[0]>array1[1])
    {
    AnimationClass a = new AnimationClass();
    a.jButtonYUp(110, 30, 100,1, jButton6);
    a.jButtonXLeft(250, 50, 100, 1, jButton6);
    a.jButtonXRight(50, 250, 100, 1, jButton5);

    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    MyTimerTask timer1_task = new MyTimerTask();
    timer1.schedule (timer1_task, 2000, 0);

    }  



 class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
 {
  public void run()
  {
     a.jButtonYDown(30, 110, 100, 1, jButton2);
  }
 }
```

Comment: I think this needs a little revising since `a` is scoped to the `if`.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for